# nsstring shows a different result when logged and when assigned

Tags: iphone, nsstring

i have the following code :

-(void)loadVersionDataToTable: (int)versionIndex{

```
OptimizationReportDate* datedVersions = [self.optimizationReport.datedResults objectAtIndex:0];
ReportDateVersion* version = [datedVersions.versions objectAtIndex:versionIndex];
ReportDateVersionSegment *seg = [version.versionSegments objectAtIndex:0];

NSString* command = (@"loadRevenueTable( %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ )",
                               (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"PageRequest"]),
                               (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"PageDisplay"]),
                               (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"Completions"]),
                               (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"CR"]),
                               (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"VistisGeneratingRevenue"]),
                               (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"RPV"]),
                               (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"AOV"]),
                               (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"TotalRevenue"]));

NSLog(@"loadRevenueTable( %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ )",
      (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"PageRequest"]),
      (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"PageDisplay"]),
      (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"Completions"]),
      (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"CR"]),
      (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"VistisGeneratingRevenue"]),
      (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"RPV"]),
      (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"AOV"]),
      (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"TotalRevenue"]));

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:command];
```

}

the nslog command prints out a the desired output of a call to the function with the right properties while the command property is assigned the last values from the retreived from the nsdictionary (the values property is a nsdictionary) this is driving me nuts ?? 
anyone ? 
the order of the log and nsstring* command does not matter also .

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually surprised that didn't give you at least a warning.  It looks like you're assigning `command` to a whole bunch of strings, so the last one is the one that sticks.  I think what you want is this.

```
OptimizationReportDate* datedVersions = [self.optimizationReport.datedResults objectAtIndex:0];
ReportDateVersion* version = [datedVersions.versions objectAtIndex:versionIndex];
ReportDateVersionSegment *seg = [version.versionSegments objectAtIndex:0];

NSString* command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"loadRevenueTable( %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ )",
                     [seg.values objectForKey:@"PageRequest"],
                     [seg.values objectForKey:@"PageDisplay"],
                     [seg.values objectForKey:@"Completions"],
                     [seg.values objectForKey:@"CR"],
                     [seg.values objectForKey:@"VistisGeneratingRevenue"],
                     [seg.values objectForKey:@"RPV"],
                     [seg.values objectForKey:@"AOV"],
                     [seg.values objectForKey:@"TotalRevenue"]];

NSLog(@"loadRevenueTable( %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ )",
      [seg.values objectForKey:@"PageRequest"],
      [seg.values objectForKey:@"PageDisplay"],
      [seg.values objectForKey:@"Completions"],
      [seg.values objectForKey:@"CR"],
      [seg.values objectForKey:@"VistisGeneratingRevenue"],
      [seg.values objectForKey:@"RPV"],
      [seg.values objectForKey:@"AOV"],
      [seg.values objectForKey:@"TotalRevenue"]);

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:command];
```

Comment: effects of coding at 2:00am ,after seeing how useless i've become i decided to go to sleep , thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
NSString* command = (@"loadRevenueTable( %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ )",
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"PageRequest"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"PageDisplay"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"Completions"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"CR"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"VistisGeneratingRevenue"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"RPV"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"AOV"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"TotalRevenue"]));
```

That's not doing what you want it to do.  Use this instead:

```
NSString* command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"loadRevenueTable( %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ , %@ )",
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"PageRequest"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"PageDisplay"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"Completions"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"CR"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"VistisGeneratingRevenue"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"RPV"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"AOV"]),
                           (@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"TotalRevenue"])];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing *really* weird stuff here! Probably coming from another language. `(a,b)` is technically C, but I would not see why you would do that.

`(a,b)` evaluates to something like: evaluate `a`, then evaluate `b`, and use the result of `b`.

so

```
(@"%@",[seg.values objectForKey:@"PageRequest"])
```

actually means

```
[seg.values objectForKey:@"PageRequest"]
```

in practice. Or I'm missing out on some new language feature.

As for your assignment to `command`, you take the last element of an `(a,b,c,..)` list as well. Use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",a,b,c]
```

instead.